# Convert Base64 encoded bytes to Int

Tags: python, base64, nonce

So basically, I generate 16 random bytes and i then convert them to Base64. I need to transform this Base64 to an Int. 
I've searched all over the internet, i found out how to convert to hex, and many other but none seem to work. 
This is the code I use to generate the nonce :

```
import base64
nonce = base64.encodebytes(os.urandom(16))
```

I need a function a bit like the parseInt() in JavaScript. The result need to be between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use parseInt() in this code if it was written in Javascript? I'd like to know what inputs and outputs you expect

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin method to convert bytes to int:

```
int.from_bytes(nonce, "big")  # big endian
int.from_bytes(nonce, "little")  # little endian
```

Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

Comment: I think this work, it generate an Int. What is "endian" ? And why did you add a "." at this end of each function ?

Comment: My bad! somehow the periods were added at the end which shouldn't be there.
Endianness determines how the bytes is stored in memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: This actually don't work, well it work but not the way i want it to work... I will update my question